# Возврат значения после AJAX запроса на Rails 6

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Как можно вернуть ответ в Rails после AJAX запроса? Например у меня есть переменная которая сформировалась после AJAX запроса и мне необходимо вернуть её обратно и встроить в HTML (показать ответ)

Контроллер:

```
def like
...
result = ...

redirect_to "..."

end
```

Запрос:

```
$.post("...", {
    apiid: "...",
    apikey: "...",
    email: "..."
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно вот так:

```
# products_controller.rb
def upvote
  @product.upvote_by current_user
  @product.create_activity :upvote, owner: current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path) }
    format.js
  end
end

# views/products/upvote.js.erb
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if current_user.voted_up_on? @product %>
    var button_html = '<%= j render(partial: 'products/downvote_button', locals: { product: @product }) %>';
    $('#vote<%= @product.id %>').html(button_html);
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Собственно, вам нужно создать вьюшку с названием экшна и расширением .js, она будет отрендерена автомагически. В ней обычным jQuery заменяете нужные элементы на странице в соответствии с полученными данными

Comment: Спасибо за четкое и понятное объяснение